# Using variables in string that is read from file

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter project, that has to read Strings from a file. These strings need to have variables in them.
For example, if i have a text file with the string "this is test $i", where i is a var in my flutter code with the value 1, the string value should be "this is test 1".
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read these values from .txt file, '$i' will not be read as a variable anymore, so i suggest replacing '$i' with a keyword you select, and replacing the keyword with your variable after you fetch the file.

Comment: Your answer is correct but you should still complete it by adding an example of code replacing the string '$i' with the value of the variable $i.

Comment: i just tried it and it works. It's not the solution i hoped for, but an acceptable work around.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).